# How to nicely format nested continuations

Tags: elm

I'm writing a lot of code like the following:

```
popStack groupTail
    |> andThen
        (\( parentGroup, parentTail ) ->
            addChild currentGroup sibling
               |> andThen
                   (\updatedParent ->
                       case sibling of

                           SingleExercise _ ->
                               workHelp siblingIndent (updatedParent :: parentTail)

                           WorkGroup _ _ ->
                               workHelp siblingIndent (sibling :: (updatedParent :: parentTail))
                  )
        )
```

It feels a lot like callback hell with all the nested `andThen` calls, and I was wondering if there are idiomatic ways to use different kinds of function application to avoid all the nesting.

Comment: Not an answer, but possibly enlightening: https://philipnilsson.github.io/Badness10k/posts/2017-05-07-escaping-hell-with-monads.html

Answer (score 3):

@Reactormonk provided a useful link, but `Elm` is not `Haskell`. Otherwise, we could use `Maybe monad` and syntactic sugar provided by `do-notation`. Something like:

```
do
  (parentGroup, parentTail) <- popStack groupTail
  updatedParent <- addChild currentGroup sibling
  case sibling of
    SingleExercise _ ->
      workHelp siblingIndent (updatedParent : parentTail)
    WorkGroup _ _ ->
      workHelp siblingIndent (sibling : (updatedParent : parentTail))
```

But in `Elm` I'd end up with moving logic into separate functions:

```
let
    workHelpToSibling sibling ( parentTail, updatedParent ) =
        case sibling of
            SingleExercise ->
                workHelp siblingIndent (updatedParent :: parentTail)

            WorkGroup ->
                workHelp siblingIndent (sibling :: (updatedParent :: parentTail))

    addChildTo currentGroup sibling ( parentGroup, parentTail ) =
        addChild currentGroup sibling
            |> Maybe.map (\updatedParent -> ( parentTail, updatedParent ))
in
    popStack groupTail
        |> andThen (addChildTo currentGroup sibling)
        |> andThen (workHelpToSibling sibling)
```

Since you have `currentGroup` and `sibling` accessible on a higher level, this code can be refactored by reducing the arity of the functions (and not only by this).

I just wanted to point out the idea of minimizing the level of indentation, which indeed reminds callback hell.